# "Сколько времени?" vs. "который час?"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "сколько времени?" или "который час"?

Answer (score -1):

По-моему, весь разговор построен на том недоразумении, что на вопрос "сколько?" нельзя ответить "сколько" и наоборот.

Но это недоразумение быстро пропадает, если от часов перейти к годам.
Об этом знают даже дети младшего школьного (а то и дошкольного( возраста.

***Тебе сколько лет? - Пять [полных], шестой пошел.

Тебе который год [пошел]? - Пять [полных], шестой пошел.***

Аналогично и с часами.

***Который час? - Одиннадцать [часов прошло с полудня, полуночи], 12-тый [пошел].***
Или: "Четверть первого, семь сорок пять, без пяти девять вечера..."

Не знаю, чего тут можно найти неправильного. Формы ответа (прошло XX часов и YY минут) иногда предопределяются ситуацией, но в целом взаимозаменяемы и равноправны. Вопрос безусловно корректен во всех отношениях.

А вот с вопросом "сколько времени" - есть небольшая "закавыка", не позволяющая распространить сферу его употребления за пределы разговорной речи. Будь это вопрос "сколько часов?" - никто бы не придрался. Но спрашивают именно о времени, - и правильно делают, одними часами тут не обойдёшься, нужны и минуты. Но время - понятие неисчислимое (правильнее бы сказать "несчетное"), в классических грамматиках использование "сколько" считалось не совсем правильным. Сейчас это ограничение давно неактуально, но это "сколько" по0прежнему за пределами высокого стиля, если ему есть традиционная исторически обоснованная замена. У нас такая замена - "который час?". А отвечать на него можно любым способом, ошибки не будет.