# Как правильно спрaшивать и отвечать о времени?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно спросить о времени?
Как грамотно ответить на вопрос "который час"?

Comment: Который час, сколько времени... и т. д. Как правильно спросить? Это хотите знать?

Comment: Подобный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/594/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-vs-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81

Comment: Еще один: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418796/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be/418816#418816

Comment: Ответ Грамоты: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_68

Answer (score 1):

Со своими можно: сколько на часах? сколько там натикало? (От "тик-так"!)

С посторонними: не скажете, который час? (Разговорный вариант: сколько времени?)

На вопросы отвечаете, например о 03.15:

начало четвёртого = за три перешагнуло = три с четвертью = четверть четвёртого = пятнадцать минут четвёртого = три пятнадцать = три часа пятнадцать минут.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты "который час" и "сколько времени" считаются равноправными, но предпочтительней спрашивать "который час". Вопрос "сколько времени" можно задавать и тогда, когда такой вопрос имеет продолжение. Например, сколько времени длится эта операция.

Распространённой ошибкой является, когда спрашивают: до скольки ты работаешь; до скольки это будет длиться. Правильно - до скОльких ты работаешь, до скОльких работает магазин. Либо - до которого часа. У слова "сколько" неподвижное ударение, поэтому - скОльких людей я встретил; скОльким людям я обязан. Недопустимо говорить "во сколько" вместо "в котором часу" или вместо "когда"!